# Select all trs from a table with a specific number of tds

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have table

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> //select this
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> //select this
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

so for the above table i want to select all trs which contains 3 tds

how could i do that with jquery?

basically i would need to get the count of such rows.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('table tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('td').length === 3;
});
```

**Notice:** [@mu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316698/select-all-trs-from-the-tabe-with-spesific-number-of-tds/7316844#7316844)  is more concise and will perform better in modern browsers. I will still leave this answer as a general demonstration for `.filter()`.

Comment: I think your second example is invalid, as `colspan` belongs on a `td` or `th`, not a `tr`

Comment: @adam: You are right, but the selector would still work. The `colspan` attribute will just have no meaning on table rows.

Comment: @mu's answer selects `tr`s having three OR MORE `td`s, yours does precisely what OP asked for.

Comment: @Michael: True... I guess it depends on actual HTML you have. If three is the maximum number of `td`s anyway, then it's fine.

Comment: @Michael: I like Felix's solution too, mostly because it is more general and hence widely applicable. Mine is a neat trick that only applies to a narrow situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could select the third `<td>` in each `<tr>` and the jump up a level to get the parent:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(3)').parent();
```

Using `:nth-child` in this case is safe because your `<tr>`s should only have `<td>` children.

For example:

```
h = $('<table><tr colspan="3"><td></td></tr><tr id="x"><td><span>x</span></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr id="y"><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>');
trs = h.find('tr td:nth-child(3)').parent();
// trs[0] is <tr id="x">
// trs[1] is <tr id="y">
```

And a demo provided by Felix Kling (now that jsfiddle.net is back in action): http://jsfiddle.net/6kMTE

Comment: @Felix: Shame that jQuery doesn't understand `:nth-of-type` so that this trick would be applicable outside the strict element nesting of a `<tr>`.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks, jsfiddle has been rather slow tonight, I had to test it in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('tr:has(td:eq(2))')
```

which selects any `tr` containing a `td` in position 3 (js is zero-based).

**Note** your html is invalid - the `colspan` belongs on the `td`, not the `tr`